# Laravel : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, migrate

I have a pivot table and I want it when the post is deleted The pivot table is also updated
at **php artisan migrate:fresh** show me this error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `test`.`category_post_pad` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `category_post_pad` add constraint `category_post_pad_post_id_foreign` foreign key (`post_id`) references `posts` (`id`) on delete cascade)

migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category_post_pad', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
        $table->foreign('post_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('posts')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedInteger('pad_id');

    });
}
```

Comment: Is the ``posts``.``id`` an integer in the migration or a bigInteger? If it's a bigInteger, there will be a conflict between its type and the type of the foreign key. Either modify the primary key of posts, or change for ``unsignedBigInteger`` for the foreign key

Comment: You will be having you Data type different for id in post table and post_id is having datatype as usignedInteger